# PushViewController Crash in IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, pushviewcontroller

I am facing strange issue in IOS7 when I try to run my old app in xcode5 with IOS6  every thing working fine,but with IOS7  when I am trying to Push  Nextview it Crash.Here is code where my app Crash.

```
 FamilyBioViewController *detailView=[[FamilyBioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FamilyBioView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
 [detailView release];
```

When crash happened it did not show any error in console.The below screenshot show the crash result
 [image]
Interesting thing is when I present my view with **presentViewController**  instead of 
**pushViewController** then it is working fine in IOS 7 .

```
FamilyBioViewController *detailView=[[FamilyBioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FamilyBioView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:nil];
 [detailView release];
```

So the Question is why pushViewController Causing problem in IOS7 ? Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Edit:
For more Detail see my app Flow [image: Here] and here is my  AppDelegate Code

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
  {
 if(tabBarController.selectedIndex==1 || tabBarController.selectedIndex==3)
 {
    [(UINavigationController *)[tabBarController selectedViewController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
  }

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
   return YES;
 }
```

Comment: what selector is being called and not there? try to enable NSZombie .. it might not be the VC even :D Who knows what your FamilyBioViewController contains

Comment: FamilyBioViewController don't have much data only have scrollview with Static Text.even when i delete every thing from the view and comment all the code after that   pushViewController did not represent the FamilyBioViewController.

Comment: Are you using ARC? I know I had the exact same issue and it was a non ARC project. I converted it to ARC and it went away.

Comment: Try running Analyze on your project. Also, expand the stack trace so you can see more detail of where it is crashing.

Comment: NO it is old project it is nonArc .i don't want to changed it to ARC.

Answer (score 0):

```
FamilyBioViewController *detailView = [[[FamilyBioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FamilyBioView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

**---- EDIT ----**
my example above it's not the solution!

**don't forget to declare your first viewController for a navigationController**

in iOS6 it wasn't a big problem. In iOS7 **it is**!

have a look to

```
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: (UIViewController *)controller]
```

You can push only if you have a root!

Comment: still the Crash happened.

Comment: thanks for your help so for please check it http://www.pastebin.ca/2476356 i am using navigation controller with UITabbar.any thing wrong there.?

Comment: no there is no Error you can see my app flow here http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2n7ghn5&s=5#.UoZTE40kjoA

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41279/discussion-between-mr-shant-and-tommaso-resti)

Answer (score 0):

The view controller in the view controller array must be unique