# UINavigation Controller Crash in IOS7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, pushviewcontroller

When i Test my App in IOS7 it Crashed at the time  when i push to NextView. After enabling Zombies i get this error.

```
[_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView frame]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I already ask this Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005721/pushviewcontroller-crash-in-ios7) but that time i was not Clear about why my app Crashed issue, So after Enabling Zoombies now i am much Clear about my issue but still don't how to Handel this issue in IOS7 ,because my app is already working fine on IOS6 and IOS5.here i would like to add some more Code which will be helpful in debuging to resolve my issue. in AppDelegate i am setting My Tabbar as a root.please see the below Code

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.5;
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
        [self.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey: nil];
```

after this i am using my UITabbarController with UInaviagtionController like this

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
  {
 if(tabBarController.selectedIndex==1 || tabBarController.selectedIndex==3)
  {
    [(UINavigationController *)[tabBarController selectedViewController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  }
  }

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
   return YES;
 }
```

As some on said me that your issue is About rootViewController, So please can any one suggest me what mistake i am doing in my Code.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't see any occurrence of "UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView", nor any code responsible for pushing it.
The problem is that "_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView" is deallocated and you are trying to do something with it. I don't think provided code is enough to say what's happen here. Edit: "after this i am assign my UITabbarController to UInaviagtionController like this"; I don't see any assigning here too.

Comment: Well you can see more detail about my issue in my previous Question that i asked.if i comment all my code that i have in FamilyBioViewController class then still before display the view it Crashed.